# How to compare two json and generate new object with same info

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two Arrays containing JSON objects: `x` and `y`. I'd like to create a new Array, `newSet`, containing all of the objects from `x` whose `serverId`s are contained in `y`. I also need to traverse through the nested objects within x.

```
var x = [
  {
    "name": "Menu",
    "serverId": "MENU",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Dashboard",
    "serverId": "DASHBOARD",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Masters",
    "serverId": "MASTERSVIEW",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "State",
        "serverId": "LOCATIONMASTER",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "City",
        "serverId": "CITYMASTER",
        "children": []
      }
  }
]

var y = ["MASTERSVIEW", "CITYMASTER", "LOCATIONMASTER"];
```

This was my attempt, but it was incorrect:

```
var newSet=[];
    for(var d=0; d<x.length;d++){
        if(x[i].serverId == y[i]){
           newSet.push(x[i]);
        }
// for inner children comparison
    }
```

Comment: x and y in your examples are not objects, they are arrays. Please elaborate more on your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
for(var  i in x){
    if(y.indexOf(x[i].serverId ) > -1) {
         newSet.push(x[i]);
    }
}
```

for inner levels you can do like this

```
function checker() {
    for(var  i in x){
        var xx = x[i];
        if(y.indexOf(xx.serverId ) > -1) {
             newSet.push(x[i]);
        }
        if(xx.children) {
            cheker(xx.children);
        }
    }
}
checker(x); // your data
```

Comment: Fine. Its workng. one more thing is. i have to check for inner children also